# Hibernate Byte code instrumentation not working for 5.1.0 version

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to do lazy loading on property level. I did byte code instrumentation for my model classes for Hibernate 4.3.11 version. It was working fine without any issue. But when I upgraded my jars to 5.1.0 same byte code instrumentation is not working.

I googled but no luck for the same. Please let me know if anybody is having any idea.

My POM.xml which was working for 4.3.11 version

<plugin>

```
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>hib-bytecode-optimize</id>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <taskdef name="instrument"  classname="org.hibernate.tool.instrument.javassist.InstrumentTask">
                                <classpath>
                                    <path refid="maven.dependency.classpath" />
                                    <path refid="maven.plugin.classpath" />
                                </classpath>
                            </taskdef>
                            <instrument>
                                <fileset dir="${basedir}/build/classes/xxx/yyy/">
                                    <include name="*.class" />
                                </fileset>
                            </instrument>
                            <echo>*** Hibernate bytecode optimization *** ${basedir}</echo>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the ANT instrument tool has been deprecated.

With 5.0 there is a grade tool that can be invoked via maven like:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        [...]
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm.tooling</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>$currentHibernateVersion</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <configuration>
                        <failOnError>true</failOnError>
                        <enableLazyInitialization>true</enableLazyInitialization>
                        <enableDirtyTracking>true</enableDirtyTracking>
                        <enableAssociationManagement>true</enableAssociationManagement>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enhance</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        [...]
    </plugins>
</build>
```